# ERROR error TS2365: Operator '<=' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'

Tags: typescript

```
createCharge() {
let a = ((document.getElementById('amount') as HTMLInputElement).value);
let b = ((document.getElementById('prescription') as HTMLInputElement).value);
let c = ((document.getElementById('vision') as HTMLInputElement).value);
let d = ((document.getElementById('clinic') as HTMLInputElement).value);
let e = ((document.getElementById('dental') as HTMLInputElement).value);
let t = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b) + parseFloat(c) + parseFloat(d) + parseFloat(e);
if (a <= t) {
  alert('total amount should less than ' + this.charge.amount);
  return false;
}
```

this is my code from ts file. this is working but its showing error. while compiling.

this is the error which i am facing:

error TS2365: Operator '<=' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, a is a string and t is a number. To compare them you would need to write

```
if (parseFloat(a) <= t)
```

I would highly recommend you revise your code to not use the native document object and its query methods. It's bad practice for Angular. Using a form would be a much better option. It would make cleaner more readable code (and much less of it). But if you dont want to include a form, the 'angular way' would be something like the following:

In the template

```
 <input type=text #amount />
 <input type=text #prescription />
 <input type=text #vision />
 <input type=text #clinic />
 <input type=text #dental />
```

In the component, make sure to import ViewChild and ElementRef

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, ... }
```

Then add these declarations to your component

```
@ViewChild('amount') amount : ElementRef;
@ViewChild('prescription') prescription : ElementRef;
@ViewChild('vision') vision : ElementRef;
@ViewChild('clinic') clinic : ElementRef;
@ViewChild('dental') dental : ElementRef;
```

And revise your method to something like the following :

```
createCharge() {
    let t = 0;
    const chargeTypes = ['amount', 'prescription', 'vision', 'clinic', 'dental'];
    chargeTypes.forEach( type => { t += parseFloat(this[type].value) }); 
    if (parseFloat(this.amount.value) <= t) {
        alert('total amount should less than ' + this.charge.amount);
        return false;
    }
 }
```

You'll notice there's a lot of redundant code in my example - this is why people use forms! A form would eliminate the need for the redundant ViewChild declarations, as you could access the values of all the different elements from a single form object.